# CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles"

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I've installed CLion and I plan to start coding on C++. I've also installed Cygwin. I've researched for the last hour or so on how a compiler works and how to use it, but when I selected the compiler on Clion I get the errors

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool."

> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage"

and

> CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows 10.

Comment: You also need to install `make` to have `cmake` work. (At least in Cygwin.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At first glance it seems to me you are missing a compiler. Do you have a compiler installed (ex: g++) or Windows equivalent? You mentioned you are using Cygwin, if you are planning to use gcc/g++ etc. take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html)

You can install them via Cygwin

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Similar problem on Fedora 30. Had to install C++ and make.

Comment: @DaveTaflin same problem I can't fix it.. No Unix Makefiles found.. Please send me links to where you installed them...

Comment: @turmuka I installed packages cmake.x86_64, gcc-c++.x86_64 and make.x86_64. No links, just the Yum package manager (e.g. shell command "sudo yum install cmake"). Are you on Fedora 30?

Comment: Got same error on my manjaro Linux. Need help.

Comment: @DebabrataSamal I'm on arch and I fixed the issue by installing make and gcc through pacman. You can do something like "sudo pacman -Syu make" and "sudo pacman -Syu gcc" to install both packages if your system uses pacman as it's manager.

Comment: @TravisGames I will try this